# Heroku client internal error for pg command

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

When trying to run any of the `heroku pg` commands I'm getting this traceback:

```
$ heroku pg

 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:       undefined method `get_attachments' for #<Heroku::API:0x007ffcf08b0390> (NoMethodError)
Backtrace:   /Users/erik/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/heroku_postgresql.rb:99:in `app_attachments'
             /Users/erik/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/heroku_postgresql.rb:104:in `hpg_databases'
             /Users/erik/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers/heroku_postgresql.rb:62:in `all_databases'
             /Users/erik/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:340:in `hpg_databases_with_info'
             /Users/erik/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:19:in `index'
             /Users/erik/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:218:in `run'
             /Users/erik/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             /usr/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku pg
Plugins:     heroku-config
             heroku-pg-extras

Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.6.0 (universal.x86_64-darwin13) ruby/2.0.0
```

All other commands work -- and the `pg` commands worked find previously.  Any thoughts on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, I resolved it by updating my [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/) as well as [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/).  I also made sure that my $PATH contained the correct location of the most recent Postgres.app installation per [these](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#troubleshooting) instructions; however Postgres.app automatically adjusted the path location when starting to the most current location.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same exact issue and opened a Heroku support ticket. They suggested I actually download a whole new toolbelt .pkg from http://toolbelt.heroku.com and install that. I had just ran

```
heroku update
```

But that didn't solve the issue even though my toolbelt version was showing 3.6.0. I downloaded the new .pkg from the link above, ran it and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Had to first uninstall the Heroku toolbelt:

```
rm -rf ~/.heroku
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/heroku /usr/bin/heroku
```

And then reinstall it. That solved the problem.